# Chevrolet cruze´s cursed thermostat housing leak

Tags: chevrolet, coolant-leak, thermostat, cruze

My father has a chevrolet cruze 2014 that one day decided to start leaking coolant from the thermostat housing. As far as I am concern, it is a fairly common problem in these cars. It has been replaced multiple times (the thermostat) but the problem still continues. I suspect that it overheats and melts. Probably, it is made from the worse plastic available.

This situation is getting us tired because it is imposible to go from a ride without checking the coolant level everytime (since if there is no coolant the temperature gauge dont work and you wouldnt notice you are overheating the car).

Do you know any posible solution for this?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Which engine does this have? I see three different ones listed.

Comment: hi, it is the 1.8 ecotec

Answer (score 1):

If the plastic thermostat housing is indeed warping or melting, replace it with a metal housing. A quick online search for **aluminum thermostat housing 2014 chevy cruze** gives numerous hits.

Comment: There are three different Cruse engines and two of them are plastic and none of them are shaped the same.